# Is $H(x) = x^2 \bmod p$ pre-image resistant, second pre-image resistant and/or collision resistant

Tags: collision-resistance, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

I have the function $H(x) = x^2\bmod p$ , where $p$ is a prime of length n bits and this function maps to the message $x$ to a n-bit hash value $H(x)$.

I need to find out if it is pre-image resistant, second pre-image resistant and/or collision resistant; and if it isn't collision resistant, what are some simple colliding messages.

I think the hash function is pre-image resistant, because for a given $x^2\bmod p$ in the output space of the hash function, it is hard to find any message $x$ with $H(x) = x^2\bmod p$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

It is neither pre-image resistant, second pre-image resistant nor collision resistant.

- It is easy to compute square-roots modulo a prime (assuming, of course, a square root exists, it will half the time).  If $p = 3 \bmod 4$, then the simple formula $x^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$ will work; for $p = 1 \bmod 4$, it's a tad more complicated but still sufficiently easy, for example, by the [Tonelli-Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm
- It is easy to compute second pre-images, even if we consider images outside the range $0 \le x < p$ to be invalid, by taking advantage of $H(x) = H(p-x)$
- The easy of computing second pre-images implies a lack of collision resistance.

Comment: Can you possibly give an example of a collision please?

Comment: @Azeem: If $p=65537$, then $H(7) = H(65530)$

Comment: If the modulus is a prime, then squaring is a 2:1 function which can easily be calculated in both directions. This can never be a cryptographic hash function.